# HtmlUnit: saving pdf link

Tags: pdf, htmlunit

How do I download a pdfLink from a website using HtmlUnit?
The default return from HtmlClient.getPage() is an HtmlPage. This does not handle pdf Files.

Comment: Before you downvote. This was a same user Q&A. It took about 20 minutes to browse the internate and piece together how to do this. So I decided to quickly share to save others the time. A bit harsh to downbote me for this, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that HtmlClient.getPage will return an UnexpectedPage if the response was not  an html file. THen you can get the pdf as an inputstream and save.

```
private void grabPdf(String urlNow)
{
    OutputStream outStream =null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        if(urlNow.endsWith(".pdf"))
        {
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
            try
            {
                setWebClientOptions(webClient);
                final UnexpectedPage pdfPage = webClient.getPage(urlNow);
                is = pdfPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();

                String fileName = "myfilename";
                fileName = fileName.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");

                File targetFile = new File(outputPath + File.separator + fileName  + ".pdf");
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                NioLog.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            finally
            {
                webClient.close();
                if(null!=is)
                {
                    is.close();
                }
                if(null!=outStream)
                {
                    outStream.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        NioLog.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

Sidenote. I didn't use try with resources because the outputstream can only be initialized within the try block. I could break into two methods but that would be cognitively slower for the programmer to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
private boolean grabPdf(String url, File output) {
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
        try {
            final UnexpectedPage pdfPage = webClient.getPage(url);
            is = pdfPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(webClient != null)
                webClient.close();
            if(is != null)
                is.close();
            if(outStream != null)
                outStream.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Suggested as an edit but rejected. This answer improves upon the original by:

- Returning `boolean` of whether or not it was downloaded
- Works with links not ending in .pdf
- Takes a `File` parameter to save the file to instead of hardcoding it in the method
- Changed FIREFOX to BEST_SUPPORTED as it is more generic suggestion (but a user may want to change it to their own needs)